# Explaining Variance

Tags: anova, variance

I am currently faced with the problem of explaining variance in an evaluation where users rate Cloud services on a quality scale.

My data looks as follows:

Dependent variable:

- Quality score (ratio scale)

Independent variable:

- loss rate (ratio scale, can easily be mapped to interval scale and represented in R as a factor with levels none, low, medium, and high).
- Delay (as loss rate)
- Jitter (als loss rate)

My problem is as follows: the quality of using a cloud service correlates with loss rates: the more loss, the less pleasant it is to use the service over the Internet. Plotting quality over loss in a scatter plot, however, shows variance that is caused by either delay or jitter: so for the same loss rate, I get variability in the obtained quality scores that is caused by either delay or jitter. It is also possible that it's purely based on the data loss as main effect.

I would like to find an approach, that gives me, for each loss rate (low, medium, high) an explanation for the variance in the obtained quality scores: was it caused purely by the loss? Or by loss and jitter, or by loss and delay?

What is the best way to approach this? I was thinking about ANOVA, but feel very uncomfortable in judging whether it is the right tool for me. Can ANOVA really help me to figure out why I see variability in quality scores for the same loss rate? Do I need a between groups or within groups test?

Is there any other way to approach this?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Don't transform your ratio scales into intervals.  Just use a linear regression with lm() (testing for all the usual assumptions, of course).  Unless I misunderstand your problem, this is exactly what regression is good for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What confuses me: assume I want to check for which ranges of losses the delay adds variability in the quality scores, how would I do that with a linear model? The delay will not always contribute the same amount of variability, but that's also something that I have to test.